# Calendar::gotoDate method recalls the ajax request defined in the events

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using fullCalendar v5 and I configured it to bind the events using an AJAX call.

Let's assume we are in Jan month 2022, if the AJAX call (http://blahblah.com//ReportDates) will return the JSON data with some date values.

Let's say the JSON data has `2021-08-01`. Now when I try to change the calendar to go to `Aug 1st 2021` date using the in-built method, the AJAX call (http://blahblah.com//ReportDates) will happen once again.

How can I prevent the second call ?

```
function calendarLoad(ReportID, ReportDate, isInitialLoad) {
  try {
    var date = new Date();
    var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    if (calendarEl != null) {
      calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        validRange: function() {
          return {
            start: '2016-01-01', //setting the start date to Jan 1st
            end: lastDay // setting the end date based on the current date
          };
        },
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'next'
        },
        events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
          var dt;
          if (ReportDate == '') {
            dt = fetchInfo.startStr.split('T')[0];
          } else {
            dt = ReportDate;
          }
          var events = [];
          $.ajax({
            url: "http://blahblah.com//ReportDates",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
              reportID: ReportID,
              startDate: isInitialLoad == true ? '' : dt
            },
            success: function(response) {
              $.map(response, function(r) {
                events.push({
                  id: r.title,
                  title: 'Available',
                  start: r.Rpt_Date,
                  allDay: true,
                  url: 'http://blahblah.com/Index/?reportID=' + btoa(ReportID) + '&reportDate=' + btoa(r.Rpt_Date),
                });
              });
              successCallback(events);
              if (response.length > 0) {
                // assigning the latest report date as initial date for calendar, this date is fetched from the ajax response
                // This method is making the ajax call once again, I just need to navigate to JSON data date and don't make the
                // ajax call once again. Rest all clicks on the calendar should work as usual after the initial load.
                calendar.gotoDate(response[0].Rpt_Date);
              } else {
                calendar.gotoDate(dt);
              }
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
              alert('Error while loading the calendar!!!');
            }
          });
        },
        eventClick: function(event) {
          if (event.event.url) {
            event.jsEvent.preventDefault();
            window.open(event.event.url, 'RHS',
              'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=No,statusbar=0,menubar=1,resizable=1,width=1050,height=590,left=50,top=50');
          }
        }
      });
    }
    calendar.render();
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Fullcalendar expects that when you run your AJAX request, you only download data which relates to the start and end dates it provides within the `fetchInfo` object. Then when you change the date, it will trigger your call again, to fetch data for the new date range. It only won't repeat that call if you have already visited that date in the calendar and downloaded data for it.

Comment: So if your AJAX call returns more data than is necessary for the dates specified by fullCalendar, then yes you will end up downloading some of the data more than once. I can see that your AJAX call doesn't send any dates to the server, so I expect this is the problem you're experiencing, because the server does not know to restrict the data it returns to the specific data range.

Comment: @ADyson, thank you for the reply. My AJAX call returns the data only once per call, so is there any possibility to stop the default ajax call on the fullCalendar date change method ? I tried to set flag on the initial call and prevent the next call but no luck...

Comment: The way to do it is exactly as I already described - make your server return only the data which is necessary for the date range that fullCalendar is currently showing. Then you won't unnecessarily download information which the user never looks at. e.g. if your system builds up a history over several years, there is no point in downloading the whole history if the user is probably only going to look at the current month, and maybe a few months in the the future. So intead of trying to prevent the AJAX, you should make the server only return the relevant data each time.